# C: char bigger than one byte?

Tags: c, char

I'm reading a buffer of type `char` from a microcontroller device like this:

```
char data_buffer[DATA_LEN];
FILE *aq_dev = fopen(argv[1], "r");

fread(data_buffer, 1, DATA_LEN, aq_dev);

fclose(aq_dev);
```

In this buffer blob there are unsigned 16bit integer numbers, each distributed over two entries in the buffer. For example there is

```
data_buffer[10] = 0x07
data_buffer[11] = 0xc3
```

which I would like to read out as `0x07c3` which equals 1987. Despite the fact that I originally thought I could just access the buffer with a `uint16_t` pointer and directly read the value, I have to do some strange bitmasking:

```
int value = (buffer[10] << 8) + buffer[11];
```

gives a **wrong value** beyond 35000 while a seemingly useless bitmasking like

```
int value = ((buffer[10] & 0xff) << 8) + (buffer[11] & 0xff);
```

returns the **correct value**.

**How can an entry of an array of `char` be bigger than one byte?**
According to my `limits.h` (Linux, x86_64) there is `#define CHAR_BIT 8`.

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with my code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `char` signed or unsigned?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that `char` is signed on your platform.  So if the high bit of `buffer[11]` is set, it will be a negative value, and when you use it in an expression it will first be promoted to a (negative) integer, effectively propagating the high bit of the `char` into all higher bit positions.

```
buffer[11]   (char)                0xc3 -61
             (int)           0xffffffc3 -61      // sign-extended
```

The reason that `&`-ing with `0xff` works is that the `char` value is promoted to `int` before the `&` operation is performed:

```
buffer[11]   (char)                0xc3 -61
             (int)           0xffffffc3 -61      // sign-extended
    & 0xff   (int)           0x000000c3 195
```

The fix is to cast to `unsigned char` before performing the bit manipulation:

```
int value = (((unsigned char) buffer[10]) << 8) | ((unsigned char) buffer[11]);

buffer[11]   (char)                0xc3 -61
             (unsigned char)       0xc3 195
             (int)           0x000000c3 195
```

It's probably easier just to make `buffer` an array of `unsigned char`.

Comment: Okay I understand your point, but why does the bitmask work then?

&-ing all 8 bits _before_ shifting them should not do anything to the value or especially to the high bit, should it?

Comment: @lynix the conversion to `int` with sign extension occurs before any arithmetic operation, including `&`.